# Удалить одинаковые строки определенных столбцов двух датафреймов

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, обработка-данных

Датафрейм df1:

```
     A    B   C    D
0  256    4  24   51
1   24   25  34  200
2  300   12  45   11
3   34   19   2   34
4   75   76  19   11
5   42   89  29  101
6   54  104  11   12
```

Датафрейм df2:

```
     E
0   25
1   12
2  104
3   12
```

Необходимо из датафрейма df1 удалить все строки, содержащие в столбце В элементы, которые встречаются в столбце Е датафрейма df2.

Мой код:

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame([[256, 4, 24, 51], [24, 25, 34, 200], [300, 12, 45, 11],
                   [34, 19, 2, 34], [75, 76, 19, 11], [42, 89, 29, 101], [54, 104, 11, 12]])
df1.rename({0: 'A', 1: 'B', 2: 'C', 3: 'D'}, axis=1, inplace=True)

df2 = pd.DataFrame([[25], [12], [104], [12]])
df2.rename({0: 'E'}, axis=1, inplace=True)

for row1 in df1.B:
    for row2 in df2.E:
        if row1 == row2:
            df1.drop(row1)
print(df1)
```

выдает ошибку "KeyError: '[25] not found in axis'"
Что не так?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Не работайте с `Pandas` циклами, это очень неэффективно. Там есть все средства, чтобы делать всё "векторно", просто и красиво:

```
df1 = df1.loc[~df1.B.isin(df2.E)]

    A   B   C   D
0   256 4   24  51
3   34  19  2   34
4   75  76  19  11
5   42  89  29  101
```

`~` - это отрицание

`isin` - функция, для проверки вхождения в `Pandas.Series` другой `Series` или списка.

Как обычно, в `Pandas` проще всё сделать с помощью фильтрации данных по условию, главное правильно составить условие.

А ошибка в вашем коде связана с тем, что вы перебираете **значения** из столбца, а функция `drop` по умолчанию считает, что ей передали **индекс(ы)** элементов, которые нужно удалить. И, конечно, в столбце `B` нет индекса `25` (а элемент есть).

Answer (score 4):

```
ids = df2["E"]
res = df1.query("B not in @ids")
```

результат:

```
In [43]: res
Out[43]:
     A   B   C    D
0  256   4  24   51
3   34  19   2   34
4   75  76  19   11
5   42  89  29  101
```